# Auto format document with Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

In Visual Studio, (and a few other Microsoft editors), you can auto format a document with a simple <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.

This inserts line breaks and tabbing automatically.

Is there a similar feature in Notepad++?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

TextFX has the options to insert line breaks and tabbing:

[image: TextFX]

Comment: Why do I not see TextFX in the menu bar as you do?

Comment: If you can not see TextFX in your menu,you can install it's plug in from http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/TextFX/TextFX%20v0.26/

Comment: TextFX can be downloaded from *Plugin Manger*

Comment: TextFX is no longer available

Answer (score 23):

For JavaScript, the [JSTool plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsminnpp/) will do this job.

[image]

Comment: very pleased with formatting result and better than tidy2

Answer (score 20):

Download the "NppAutoIndent" plugin.  In Notepad++:

> Plugins → Plugin manager → Available → NppAutoIndent

The "NppAutoIndent" plugin has 'smart' indentation for C-style languages, such as C/C++, PHP, and Java. 
It's the first release, so don't expect it to be flawless, and of course it might not be completely to your preferences. 
There is NO support for HTML/XML and such, maybe later, tag matching is much more difficult to implement. 
To use it, select your code and:

> TextFX → TextFX Edit → Reindent C++ code

If you cannot see `TextFX` in your menu, you can install its plugin
from [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/TextFX/TextFX%20v0.26).

References:

- [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Plugin_Central)
- [Notepad++ Home (notepad-plus-plus.org)](https://notepad-plus-plus.org)
- Brief mention in [Auto-indent in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412427/auto-indent-in-notepad) (on Stack Overflow)
- [Reindenting C Source Code Files With Notepad++](http://www.andrewhazelden.com/blog/2012/02/reindenting-c-source-code-files-with-notepad/) (blog)

Comment: This seems a bit of a jumbled answer to me. Are you talking about NppAutoIndent or TextFX? It seems to jump from one to the other.

Comment: Neither of these plugins are available anymore

Answer (score 5):

For markup / xml there's a plugin called 'XML Tools'.

This can be added via the plugin manager inside Notepad++.

Comment: It can't seem to clean HTML it just says errors in the document without telling me what they are.

Answer (score 4):

Here are most of plugins to format your code.

> **JStool (JSmin):**
>   UniversalIndentGUI ( Enable `text auto update' in plugin manager-> UniversalIndentGUI`
>   Shortkey = `CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+J` )

---

> **TextFX :**  ( Shortkey = `CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+B` or `TextFX > TextFX Html Tidy > Tidy: reindent XML`)
>   TextFX has the benefit of wrapping long lines, which XML Tools does not do, but doesn't indent those new lines correctly.

---

> **XML Tools :**  (customized plugin for XML;   Shortkey = `CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+B` or `XML Tools > Pretty print [Text indent]`)
>   XML Tools complements TextFX by indenting the newly wrapped lines nicely.

Answer (score 1):

For JSON documents, the `JSON Viewer` plugin allows a simple `CTRL-ALT-SHIFT-M` to format the json.